# Strange behavior in Date constructor

Tags: javascript

Here's a little excerpt from my Javascript console:

```
> x
"Dec 16, 2012 03:40 PM"
> typeof(x)
"string"

> new Date(x)
Invalid Date

> new Date("Dec 16, 2012 03:40 PM")    
Sun Dec 16 2012 15:40:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

I am stumped about why `new Date(x)` doesn't work whereas if I pass the same string directly, it works fine. Does anyone know?

Comment: I am using the latest Chrome, by the way

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle showing this behaviour please?

Comment: Works fine in latest Chrome here http://jsbin.com/irowuh/1/edit. Problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: *"`new Date(x)` doesn't work whereas if I pass the same string directly, it works fine"* I don't believe you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

It appears that my variable had some exotic whitespaces that were removed each time I'd copy the string from the console.

`new Date(x.replace(/\s+/, ' '))` worked.